# как правильно обработать запрос браузера и настроить маршрутизацию?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Делаю маршрутизацию URL приложения на прием запросов с URL которые не соответствуют реальным файлам приложения.
**index.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'application/bootstrap.php';
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
require_once 'core/Model.php';
require_once 'core/View.php';
require_once 'core/Controller.php';
require_once 'core/Route.php';
Route::start();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Маршрутизация в отдельном файле Route.php в директорию core. В этом файле класс Route, который будет запускать методы контроллеров, которые в свою очередь будут генерировать вид страниц.

```
 static function start()
{
    $controller_name = 'Main';
    $action_name = 'Index';

    $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    var_dump($routes);
    if (!empty($routes[2])) {
        $controller_name = $routes[2];
    }

    if (!empty($routes[3])) {
        $action_name = $routes[3];
    }

    $model_name = 'Model' . $controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller' . $controller_name;
    $action_name = 'action' . $action_name;

    $model_file = $model_name . '.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/" . $model_file;
    if (file_exists($model_path)) {
        include "application/models/" . $model_file;
    }
    $controller_file = $controller_name . '.php';
    $controller_path = "application/controllers/" . $controller_file;
    if (file_exists($controller_path)) {
        include "application/controllers/" . $controller_file;
    } else {
        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

    $controller = new $controller_name;
    $action = $action_name;

    print $controller_name;
    echo "<br/>";
    print $action;


    if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        $controller->$action();
    } else {
        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }
}

function ErrorPage404()
{
    print "trouble";
    $host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    header('Location:' . $host . '404');
}
```

При вызове в строке браузера ***localhost:63942/Server/*** - 
вызывает контроллер по умолчанию и все срабатывает как надо, но при
***localhost:63942/Server/Main***
**localhost:63942/Server/Main/index**
**localhost:63942/Server/Server**
выкидывает

> 404 Not Found PhpStorm 2016.1.2

хотя у меня есть обработка и вывод `function ErrorPage404()`. и в данном случае при данных запросах должны срабатывать контроллеры и показывать нужные мне views.
на запрос **localhost:63342/Server/index.php** выкидывает уже мою ошибку

ссылка проекта на гитхаб https://github.com/MaximDzhezhelo/Server

Подскажите в чем проблема, почему на нужный запрос в браузере получаю 404 Not Found?
как правильно обработать запрос браузера и настроить маршрутизацию?

Comment: kogda nabiratete localhost:63942/Server/Main/index 
chto ljit v peremennix $controller_name i $action_name ?

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan не могу прочитать что там лежит, так как выкидывает 404 Not Found PhpStorm 2016.1.2, не знаю как просмотреть в таком случае, выкидывает не мою ошибку(

Comment: poetomu v mesto  Route::ErrorPage404(); napishi echo 'methoda netu' ili echo 'fayl ne nayden'. togda budet ponyatno gde obrivaetsya.Esli file nee nayden togda nado iskat v htaccess,poprobuy tam napisat sleduyusche RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js) index.php

Comment: pochmu xampp ne polzushsya ili cho nibud drugoe,ya prviy raz viju chtobi polzovalis cheres phpshtorm,eto ne profesionalno,poslushay moy sovet

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan тут нужно писать на русском. Что не так с phpstorm?

Comment: Я никогда н пользовался им,Не знаю какая там сборка.А xanpp  точно apache ,где уж точно твой htaccess  будет  работать

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan на запрос localhost:63342/Server/index.php выкидывает уже мою ошибку. пробовал в htaccess  поменять на то что вы сказали, не помогает

Comment: @makson Я не буду устанавливать шторм дабы проверить.Сказал же установите xampp и перетащите файлы в xampp/htdocs/.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan скорей всего проблема все-таки в настройках phpstorm, постараюсь настроить его. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm по умолчанию использует встроенный веб-сервер PHP.

настройка раутинга для него описана в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) PHP:

вас интересует пример 3 - router script

в PhpStorm настройка router script тоже описана в [руководстве](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/php-built-in-web-server.html):  `to have a specific script always executed upon the server start-up, select the Use router script check box and specify the path to the script in the text box.`

проще говоря, не гадайте, а RTFM.

P.S. (из комментов)  профессионально или нет использовать встроенный PHP-сервер - это настолько субъективный вопрос, что даже не хотелось бы отвечать на него. Это вполне ок, если вы знаете, что вы делаете и не занимаетесь низкоуровневым бэкэндом (90% php-кодеров не занимаются). Ваша задача как профессионала - писать хороший, быстрый, красивый код.

Если бы ЭТО было "непрофессионально", то ставить xampp/lamp тоже  непрофессионально.

По хардкору - нужно завести ферму linux-серверов с полным стаком выкладки (ansible/git), балансерами и репликацией, и уж с ними работать, тогда ты уж профи

"Домашний кодер просто СОШЕЛ С УМА когда УВИДЕЛ ЭТОТ ПРОДАКШЕН"

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста про Use router script check box, туда надо вставлять .htaccess (его не видно через select) или  router script? прочитал документацию но не понял что с ним делать и где он должен лежать.

Comment: router script работает просто - если он возвращает false, то  делается попытка прочитать файл, или он возвращает любые другие данные (или заголовки) т.е. router script это такой продвинутый htaccess для локальной разработки, вам, кстати, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765753/routing-php-5-4-built-in-web-server-like-htaccess вот этот ответ поможет, думаю.

Comment: спасибо! помогло