# Отлов ошибки отсутствия файла

Tags: php, веб-программирование, обработка-ошибок

Я пишу код сайта, проверяю его во **встроенном PHP-сервере** (php7-cli). Всё было хорошо, но я начал осваивать **MVC**, но тут вдруг выяснилось что встроенный сервер **не поддерживает .htaccess**. Есть выход с помощью написания роутера и указания его в параметре вызова сервера, но при этом появляется проблема, **в терминал не выводятся ошибки**. Приходится чуть-ли не перед каждым **require_once** писать сообщение что файл подключен. Потом замучаюсь это всё убирать при публикации сайта, подскажите нормальное решение пожалуйста.

Мне нужно отловить все сообщения связанные с отсутствием:

1. файла
2. класса
3. метода

Нужно типа своего обработчика ошибок (типа **set_error_handler** или **set_exception_handler**) определённого типа, но разбираться со всем этим пока к сожалению времени нет.

Добавлено: вопрос с "молчанием" терминала уже решён

Comment: какой фреймворк для mvc используется?

Comment: а вариант поставить апач+xdebug на локалке не рассматривается?

Comment: см ответ здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540612/, и проапдейтите вопрос, вам что нужно-то в итоге, если вопрос с молчанием терминала решен? Кроме того, терминал вам не нужен, вам надо настроить в ini логи и поставить какой-нибудь просмотрщик логов или аналог tail для винды

Comment: @strangeqargo От того что вопрос с "молчанием" терминала решился, корень вопроса не изменился. Чтобы не повторяться, начиная со слов "Мне нужно" в вопросе написано что мне нужно. Простите но какая разница куда выводятся ошибки, хоть в терминал, хоть в логи. Но за совет спасибо

Comment: @Igor Свой, самописный. Скорее даже не фреймворк, просто придерживаюсь идеалогии mvc при написании

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Нет. Ставить монстра, настраивать сначала его, потом XDebug, для моих потребностей излишне.

Comment: @tonchikp погодите, если вам нужно отлавливать все сообщения кроме некоторых - вы можете 1) настроить php (настройте выдачу только fatal errors) - хотя игнорировать ворнинги - глупо, 2) настроить фильтрацию вывода логов через греп. других вариантов у вас нет.

Comment: @strangeqargo Нет, если закрывать глаза на другие ошибки это очень плохо, это не вариант. Я думал может есть решение где например все остальные ошибки обрабатываются как обычно (и ломать такое представление мне бы не хотелось), а только отсутствие файла например обрабатывать по своему, выводить сообщение, но централизованно, то есть не возле каждой ошибки (типа try catch), а повесить обработчик на определённый тип ошибок

Comment: @strangeqargo grep - это конечно здорово, если ничего нет другого придётся принять это решение, но может есть попроще решение, внутри PHP? А что скажете о тех функциях которые я упомянул в вопросе, в них не может быть решение?

Comment: @tonchikp  насколько я помню, вы можете перенаправить fatal errors в один лог, warnings в другой, parsing errors  в третий. Не знаю, насколько это полезно, я предпочитаю все ошибки иметь в одном логе, а ошибки конкретных скриптов/программ - в их собственном дополнительном логе. В перехвате ошибок может быть решение, конечно, но только для вашей конкретной ситуации. Я бы не стал этим особо заморачиваться. Эти обработчики нужны скорее для встроенных дебаггеров (вы можете их через composer подтянуть) - для удобства отображения ошибок

Comment: @strangeqargo спасибо за информацию, буду изучать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопроса я не понял, но чтобы ни одна ошибка не пропала, сервер надо настраивать так:

- На домашнем сервере, выводим на экран и пишем в лог

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('log_errors', 1);
  ```
- На боевом сервере блокируем вывод на экран и пишем в лог

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  ini_set('log_errors', 1);
  ```

Comment: Это уже сделано в базовом файле который подключается require_once. Не помогает, ошибки не выводятся, вообще

Comment: @Ипатьев Каким образом? @ - не использую нигде